# The element is not clicked if the element is not visible on the screen even if it is displayed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

If the element is present in the html but, for the element to come into view it needs to be scrolled up.

When clicking on this element Selenium webdriver does not throws any error but it does not click and moves to the next step without clicking.

Any way to check if it is not displayed, because `ele.isDisplayed()` returns true.

Edit : It is the problem with Internet Explorer only it seems.

Comment: By design, webdriver can do only what user can do in the browser. User cannot click element which s not visible, so what would be use case for automated activity which user cannot do? How it would help testing?

Comment: should it not show it as not displayed then? How can both hold true? i.e. it shows it as displayed and it can't click. I am going into the argument of how it would help testing.

I wanted to know if there is any way i could identify that it is not displayed on the page, so that i can handle it appropriately.

Comment: if the objective is to check if element is displayed, you can use JSExecutor or the element.size!=0 condition.

Comment: [display vs visibility in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility) iow, displayed element might be rendered (taking space on the page)  but invisible (hidden)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [display vs visibility in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475119/css-properties-display-vs-visibility)

Displayed element might be rendered (taking space on the page)  but invisible (hidden)

Comment: this is a great read. +1

Comment: does not answer my question. The element on my page does not have any different property..!

Comment: I really do not understand your comment. Link above explains the situation when element is displayed, but not visible, as you asked in your question, and why not allowing it to be clickable (because user could not click on it) is correct handling of the conditions. Is your element visible? What other different properties are you talking about?